# Is NLog.Redis supported on .NET Core?

Tags: redis, .net-core, logstash, kibana, nlog

My previous project which is written on .NET Framework is using NLog.Redis to log information and visualize it on Kibana through Logstash. Is NLog.Redis supported on .NET Core to use in my new project?

Comment: See also: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.Redis

Answer (score 0):

Currently there there is no .NET Standard (and so .NET Core) version released.

There is an open pull request for it, see https://github.com/richclement/NLog.Redis/pull/7